# PYTHON: Import .txt file (data for temperature and years) and find the average for k years

Tags: python, average

The user to input k years to average (From 1-60 years) through importing the data from the .txt file. How would I approach this?

Comment: look into http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 3):

file.txt:

```
50
25
70
18
90
```

Python:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    temps = [int(l.strip()) for l in f.readlines()]

print(sum(temps) / len(temps)) # 50.6
```

Comment: Since there's only one number per line, the `l.strip()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Nicolas' answer, if you are going to do more complicated processing later on that requires [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org), you can do

```
import numpy, sys
a = numpy.loadtxt('file.txt')
m = a.mean()
sys.stdout.write('mean = %f\n'%m)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What is the reason you aren't using `print` here? Habit?

Comment: Yeah, habit. I got wary of using `print` because of the Python 2.x <-> 3.x problem.

Comment: If you _know_ you're not going to use Python < 2.6, you can do `from __future__ import print_function` and then use the function-form of `print`.

Comment: IMHO, it seems odd then that you don't use the `from __future__ import...` and use `print()` yourself.

Comment: @martineau Again, if you have to support Python older than 2.6, the `from __future__ import print_function` is not going to work. What's odd about that?